# virtualenv venv not activating or creating the required folder

Tags: python, django, pip, virtualenv

I'm following the following guide to install virtualenv on my Windows 64bit machine :
http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/

I have already installed virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper using pip. 
Now, it says under the basic usage topic to cd into my project folder and type 'virtualenv venv' that will create the folder venv.

But when I do this, my cmd cursor just moves on to the next line and continues to blink forever. 
[image]

Am I missing anything here?

Comment: Did you press `enter` after `virtualenv venv`?

Comment: Yes I did. It's a screen shot so probably the cursors not appearing.

Comment: How long have you waited? What does `virtualenv --version` show?

Comment: Waited for more than 15 minutes. None of the virtualenv commands are returning anything, even --version.

Comment: How did you install `virtualenv`? What does `pip list` show?

Comment: I followed these steps: 
1. pip install virtualenv
2. pip install virtualenvwrapper

My pip list shows the following :
C:\Users\Bhavin>pip list
Django (1.8.7)
mysql-connector-python (2.1.3)
nltk (3.1)
oauthlib (1.0.3)
pbr (1.8.1)
pip (7.1.2)
pymongo (3.1.1)
pytz (2015.7)
requests (2.8.1)
requests-oauthlib (0.5.0)
setuptools (7.0)
six (1.10.0)
stevedore (1.9.0)
tweepy (3.4.0)
virtualenv (13.1.2)
virtualenv-clone (0.2.6)
virtualenvwrapper-powershell (12.7.8)
virtualenvwrapper-win (1.2.1)

Comment: It has virtualenv(13.1.2), virtualenv-clone(0.2.6) and it's installed in the site-packages folder of python27

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96196/discussion-between-user1650978-and-davejagoda).

Comment: Brief summary from chat - all invocations of `virtualenv` seem to hang, but no other obvious problems have been found.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a temporary fix for this, I'm using Python 2.7.9 along with virtualenv 13.1.2.

None of the normal virtualenv commands were returning anything, so I tried `python -m <followed-by-the-desired-script>` .

This worked, I could activate my virtual environment, but again, within the environment, `pip install django` did not work, so within the environment I ran : `python -m pip install django` that installed django in my virtual environment directory.

I don't know what the issue is, maybe its to do with the versions, or maybe with virtualenv's script itself. Hoping to find a proper solution for it soon.